# extjs 4.0 delegate to the parent node on mouse over

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I wanted to to delegate the mouseover/mouseout event to my parent node.

Here in the below code when i roll over to the **#mycontent > span.bannerContent**, i should delegate my mouseover event to the parents child **img#bannerImage**.

How i can achieve using extjs

**HTML code:**

```
<div>  
  <img id="bannerImage" />
<div id="mycontent"> 
    <span> my dummy content </span>
</div>
```

**EXtJS code**

```
items : [{
            xtype: 'image',
            id:'bannerview1',
            src: 'images/homePage/banner-1.jpg',
            height: 500,
            width: 1240,
            listeners: {
                el: {
                    click: function(el,src) {
                    var link =src.src;
                    if(link.indexOf("banner-1.jpg")!= -1){
                        window.open("main");
                     }                   
                    }
                }
            }
           },
           {
                xtype: 'box',
                id:'label',                      
                html: '<span class="bannerContent"></span> ',
                listeners: {
                     **el: {
                       mouseover:function(){

                       },
                       mouseout:function(){

                       }**
                     }
                }   
            }
    ]
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by passing the event to the other element? Isn't it better to manipulate this element directly from the bannerImage event handlers using dom traversal up and down functions? Or directly by id lookup, if it is unique on the whole page.

Comment: No we have implemented carousel like stuff, but not exactly a carousel, but it is implemented using the taskrunner in extjs. We are actually stopping the taskrunner on mouseover to that banner content which is inside mycontent span. So when mouseout of this element again the taskrunner started which should not be the case, so i thought a event delegation to the parents child element (img) will work to solve this problem.  Please suggest me a solution if i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can pass an event to any observable using relayEvent, but the problem is, that Ext.dom.Element is not observable (does not know fireEvent method). So either you can listen to mouse events on parent div, hook carousel also on box events or if you insist on relaying events, extend Ext.Img such that it fires mouseout and mouseover events itself (and not its 'el') and then hook your carousel on such events.

```
Ext.define('My.Img',{
    extend: 'Ext.Img',
    alias: 'widget.myimage',

    initComponent: function(){
        var me = this;
        me.addEvents('mouseover','mouseout');
        me.on('render',function(){
            me.getEl().relayEvent('mouseover',me);
            me.getEl().relayEvent('mouseout',me);
        });

        me.callParent();
    }
});

var myImage = Ext.create('My.Img',{
    id:'bannerview1',
    height: 500,
    width: 1240,
    src: '/img/header_01.gif',
    listeners: {
        mouseover:function(e){
            console.log('mouseover image');
        },
        mouseout:function(e){
            console.log('mouseout image');
        }
    }
});

Ext.create(' ... ',{
    ...
    items : [ myImage,
        {
            xtype: 'box',
            id:'label',
            html: '<span class="bannerContent">blablabla</span> ',
            listeners: {
                render: function(){
                    this.getEl().relayEvent('mouseover',myImage);
                    this.getEl().relayEvent('mouseout',myImage);
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Personally I think that such solution is not very straightforward.